# Creating a Node Class

Tags: java, list

I'm studying Cracking the Coding Interview, and the code for constructing a Node class has a int data variable. What is the point of this variable? What does it refer to in the list?

Comment: Some unknown code uses an int, and you're asking us to know what it is for? How could we know? Post the code.

Comment: it would be holder of data within node. Can you paste the definition of node?

Answer (score 1):

The field

```
int data
```

is an example of what you hold inside a node, an element that you actually care for in the list.

Let's say you want to keep a list of integers in given order. The **data** field is your **integer** (for example profit of your company in some preconfigured order), while the **Node object** encapsulates it and also holds a reference to the next object (in single linked list)